# What exactly did Ramsey’s question mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fast X* (2023), RAMSEY took his team to old computer shop:

> ROMAN: Wait, so we gonna find military-grade gear in the middle of
> London?
>
> RAMSEY: You said you wanted to shop off the grid.
>
> ROMAN:  Wait a second. Did we just time-travel?
>
> RAMSEY: **Would you look for a black-market operation in a place like
> this?**

Tej Parker didn’t answer as if the question was rhetorical and nodded his head as if he understood.

What exactly did Ramsey’s question mean?

I think Ramsey suggests that the old computer shop, an unlikely
location for a black-market operation, could be a good place to hide illegal activities.

Comment: Your interpretation makes sense to me. That's my first guess without having seen the movie

Comment: Are you writing your English dissertation on Shakespeare? Dickens? The Diary of Anne Frank, perhaps? Something even more modern? Cloud Atlas? No... the script of 'Fast X' starring Vin Diesel.

Comment: @Astralbee Nailed it. ‘Fast X’ is the **peak of literary achievement**.